# The product of disks $D^m \times D^n$ is homeomorphic to $D^{m + n}$

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry

Consider the disk
$$D^n = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb R^n \mid \lVert x \rVert\le 1 \}.$$
I know it is a common result that
$$D^m \times D^n \cong D^{m +  n}.$$
Intuitively it seems quite understandable, if you take $n = m = 1$ then $D^m \times D^n$ just becomes the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ which can be deformed into the disk $D^2$. Similarly, if $n = 1, m = 2$, then we get the cylinder $D^2 \times [0,1]$ which can be deformed into the ball $D^3$. However, I cannot see what is the explicit isomorphism for every $m, n$, could one of you help me with this ?

Comment: If you are only interested in showing that they are homeomorphic, then you can do induction and it is enough to show that $D^1 \times D^1 \cong D^2$.

Comment: A dupe. It was asked and answered many times that convex subsets are homeomorphic to the unit ball.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $H_n=[0,1]^n$. Then prove by induction on $n$ that $D_n \cong H_n$.

Based on that

$$D_n \times D_m \cong H_n \times H_m \cong H^{n+m} \cong D^{n+m}$$ follows.

Answer (score 1):

One way to see it is via this homeomorphism:
$$
D^m\times D^n\ni(x,y)\mapsto \left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\max\{|x|,|y|\}}{\sqrt{|x|^2+|y|^2}}(x,y)
& \text{if} & (x,y)\ne(0,0) \\
(0,0)  & \text{if} & (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{array} 
\right. \in D^{m+n}
$$
where $|\cdot|$ is the $\ell^2-$norm in the corresponding space.